# Increase Azure Webapp for containers timeout

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to send a big file to one of my APIs hosted as an "Azure Webapp for containers" Linux service.

However, I am getting timed out while data transfer. So, wanted to increase it to 10 mins.

Is there some way to do it?

PS: Using Flask to serve the API

Comment: @RenanAraújo Nope. I think the answer from msft here, pretty much says that the timeout cant be increased :(

Comment: https://github.com/rajkumar-rangaraj/MAWSFileExplorer/issues/3#issuecomment-220552508